# nginx one ipaddress but 2 sites served from subfolder

Tags: nginx, subdomain, subdirectory

I have succesfully configured nginx. with default site it works correctly.
Now i have 2 sites, one at /home/bugz and another one /home/git/github/public. and only one ip 10.10.10.10 (i dont have dns setup hence cant use domain names)
i want to have the sites served at locations

```
http://10.10.10.10/bugz and http://10.10.10.10/github respectively
```

below are the two config files

```
server {
  listen  *:80;
  server_name 10.10.10.10;
  server_tokens off;
  root /home/bugz;

   # individual nginx logs for this gitlab vhost
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/bugzilla_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/bugzilla_error.log;

  location /bugz {
      index  index.html index.htm index.pl;
  }


  location ~ \.pl|cgi$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      gzip off;
      fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:8999;
      fastcgi_index index.pl;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
      }
}
```

and

```
upstream gitlab {
  server unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket;
}

server {
#  listen *:80 default_server;         # e.g., listen 192.168.1.1:80; In most cases *:80 is a good idea
  listen *:80;         # e.g., listen 192.168.1.1:80; In most cases *:80 is a good idea
  server_name 10.10.10.10;     # e.g., server_name source.example.com;
  server_tokens off;     # don't show the version number, a security best practice
  root /home/git/gitlab/public;

  # individual nginx logs for this gitlab vhost
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  location /{
    # serve static files from defined root folder;.
    # @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
  }

  # if a file, which is not found in the root folder is requested,
  # then the proxy pass the request to the upsteam (gitlab unicorn)
  location @gitlab {
    proxy_read_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_connect_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab;
  }

  }
```

How do i achieve this ?

Comment: Do you use a `sites-available` in your config directory?

Comment: yes sites-available is used in my config

Answer (score 1):

Your `nginx.conf` should contain something like this inside the `http` block :

```
 include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

Then you will have 2 configuration files in the `/etc/nginx/sites-available` folder.  (which has symlinks directed from the `sites-enabled` folder.

Each conf will need to either have them listening on a different ports; ie one on port 80 and on one port 81

server1.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
```

server2.conf

```
server {
    listen       81;
    server_name  localhost;
```

-OR-

Have a different `servername` for each server in the conf files and play with the hosts file.

Comment: Ye i do have the /etc/nginx/sites-available enabled and have proper symlinks in sites-enabled.

Comment: Ye i do have the /etc/nginx/sites-available enabled and have proper symlinks in sites-enabled.
i would not like to have the two diff sites on 2 diff port. they shud work on the same port80.
can you please explain on the 2nd option? how can i have different servername? i have only one interface 10.10.10.10 (no dns configured, hence cant use hostnames names)
when you say "play with hosts files" what are you suggesting, can you please explain, i a am very new to nginx. it was easy in apache, put the two sites under 2 folders in /var/www/ and thats it. dont we have something similar in nginx ?

Comment: If you do not have DNS setup I do not believe this will work.  YOu need to tell ngnix to listen for different hostnames/servernames.  Using an IP address alone will not suffice for 2 sites on the same port.

Comment: @sparkbird - you might be able to use a re-write rule if your URL requests will always have the folder appended to the end.  I do not have much experience with rewriting URLs however.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why this huge configs, I'd configure only 1 site with 2 locations

```
server {
    server_name 10.10.10.10;
    location /bugz {
        root /root/to/bugz;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/bugzilla_access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/bugzilla_error.log;
        index  index.html index.htm index.pl;
        # try_files statement
    }
    location /git {
        root /home/git/gitlab/public;
        #access and error log and rest of config
    }
    location ~ \.pl|cgi$ { }
    location @gitlab { }
}
```